# linux setuid does not work

Tags: linux, c, setuid

I am learning linux suid,so I have written a small c program with the following content to test it

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
system("echo 100 >> test.txt");
return 0;
}
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 8004 Sep 10 16:19 test
```

`test.txt` is a file which can only be modified by root

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root
```

If I run the test program with a user account, it should add `100` to the empty file.
But, it comes out:

```
sh:test.txt:Permission denied
```

Why?

Comment: What happens when you run the program as root?

Comment: If you change `echo 100 >> test.txt` to `id -u`, what does that print?

Comment: What is the output when you type `/bin/sh --version` ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem is, you call the function `system()`, which calls a shell `/bin/sh`. And the shell `/bin/sh` has no suid bit set. Thats why is prints the `Permission denied` message.

You have to write the part in pure c code:

```
int main() {
  FILE *fd = fopen("test.txt", "a");
  fprintf(fd, "%s", "100");
  fclose(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe it's not so much that `/bin/sh` doesn't have the suid bit set as it is that the shell explicitly sets its UID back to the caller's real UID.

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario works perfectly here for me.

```
$ ls -l test*
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root  root  6776 Jan 24 17:18 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 chris chris   74 Jan 24 17:18 test.c
-rw-r----- 1 root  root     0 Jan 24 17:20 test.txt
$ ./test
ls -l test.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root root 4 Jan 24 17:21 test.txt
$ sudo cat test.txt
100
```

Is it possible that you're testing your program on a filesystem that does not permit setuid executables? Run the `mount` command and look for `nosuid` against the filesystem, such as here:

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

Comment: Did you do this in root account or other user account?

Comment: An ordinary non-root account