# SUID bit on binary file still yielding "Permission denied" error

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

`alice` and `bob` both belong to the `staff` group.

I've got the following folder:

`drwxrwxr-x 2 alice staff 4096 Oct 30 14:45 share`

with the following files inside the folder:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 alice alice 8768 Oct 30 14:45 display-foo
-rw------- 1 alice alice 24 Oct 30 14:45 foo.txt
```

`display-foo` is a **binary** file that essentially displays the contents of `foo.txt` using the `cat` command.

When `alice` runs `./display-foo`, the binary file executes successfully and the contents of  `foo.txt` are displayed. However, when `bob` runs `./display-foo`, the binary file executes successfully but the contents of the `foo.txt` are **not displayed**, yielding the error `/bin/cat: /home/alice/share/foo.txt: Permission denied`.

---

From my understanding, setting the setuid bit allows the binary executable to be executed with the privileges of the file's owner (in this case, `alice`). Why, then, was `bob` not allowed to view the contents of `foo.txt`?

---

**ADDENDUM**: I have recompiled my **binary** file with the `geteuid()` function so that it prints out the effective user ID (EUID). Indeed, when `bob` executes the binary file, the EUID is that of `alice`. Yet, permission is denied. Here's a snippet of the source code:

```
printf("%d", geteuid());
system("/bin/cat /home/alice/share/foo.txt");
```

Comment: @SatōKatsura Yup, it is a binary file (compiled using gcc from a .c program).

Comment: Commands run with `system()` don't inherit the privileged UID.  Try `fopen()` etc. instead.

Comment: Thank you @SatōKatsura , it works like a charm. I'm guessing this is some sort of security feature by Ubuntu.

Comment: Nope, it's standard UNIX semantics.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (running Debian 9, GCC 6.3.0). The setuid bit seems to be doing its job, even with the `system` call. Any thoughts?

Comment: @igal Interesting. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with GCC 5.4.0. Let me try to see - later this week - whether upgrading the OS and/or GCC makes a difference. I couldn't find any information regarding which commands can "inherit... privileged UID[s]" and which cannot.

Comment: @JTJM I wanted to post what I tried, just as a sanity check. But it's way too long for a comment, so I posted it as a solution. If you get a chance maybe let me know if it looks right.

Answer (score 3):

I read through the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) for the `system` function and came across the following passage which offers an explanation:

> ```
> Do not use system() from a program with set-user-ID or set-group-ID
> privileges, because strange values for some environment variables
> might be used to subvert system integrity.  Use the exec(3) family of
> functions instead, but not execlp(3) or execvp(3).  system() will
> not, in fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-
> group-ID privileges on systems on which /bin/sh is bash version 2,
> since bash 2 drops privileges on startup.  (Debian uses a modified
> bash which does not do this when invoked as sh.)
> ```

Here are some other StackExchange posts that I read through on my way to that passage:

- [SETUID Permission Denied](https://serverfault.com/questions/372298/setuid-permission-denied)
- [Why do I need setuid(0) within a setuid-root C program that calls an administrative program with system()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051370/why-do-i-need-setuid0-within-a-setuid-root-c-program-that-calls-an-administrat)
- [Debugging a setuid program / “Permission denied” with setuid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169656/debugging-a-setuid-program-permission-denied-with-setuid)
- [Unix suid bit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003177/unix-suid-bit-problem)
- [how to set the setuid bit in a program of a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536846/how-to-set-the-setuid-bit-in-a-program-of-a-non-root-user)
- [linux setuid does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180828/linux-setuid-does-not-work)

For posterity, and because the given example might be useful for diagnosing this or similar issues in other contexts, I've kept my original below.

---

Is it possible that you're running into a bug? I was unable to reproduce your problem in a Docker container running Debian 9 with gcc 6.3. Here is how I went about trying to recreate the scenario described in your post.

First create the "alice" and "bob" users and them to the "staff" group:

```bsh
useradd -m -G staff alice
useradd -m -G staff bob
```

Next create the file and set its ownership and permissions:

```bsh
# Create a subdirectory to hold the text file
sudo -u alice mkdir -p /home/alice/share/

# Create the text file
sudo -u alice bash -c 'echo "This is foo.txt" > /home/alice/share/foo.txt'

# Set restrictive permissions on the text file
chmod u=rw,g=,o= /home/alice/share/foo.txt
```

Let's check the results:

```
$ ls -l /home/alice/share/foo.txt
-rw------- 1 alice alice 16 Nov  4 15:33 /home/alice/share/foo.txt
```

Now let's create a version of `display-foo` which uses the `system` function:

```
$ cat <<HEREDOC > /usr/local/src/display-foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    struct passwd *r_pwd = getpwuid(getuid());
    printf("Real user: %s\n", r_pwd->pw_name);

    struct passwd *e_pwd = getpwuid(geteuid());
    printf("Effective user: %s\n", e_pwd->pw_name);

    system("/bin/cat /home/alice/share/foo.txt");
}
HEREDOC

$ gcc /usr/local/src/display-foo.c -o /usr/local/bin/display-foo
```

And let's set ownership and permissions on `display-foo`, including setting the setuid bit:

```bsh
chown alice:alice /usr/local/bin/display-foo
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx /usr/local/bin/display-foo
chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/display-foo
```

Let's also check the result:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/display-foo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 alice alice 8640 Nov  4 15:40 /usr/local/bin/display-foo
```

Now we run the program both as `alice` and as `bob`:

```bsh
$ sudo -u alice display-foo

Real user: alice
Effective user: alice
This is foo.txt

$ sudo -u bob display-foo

Real user: bob
Effective user: alice
This is foo.txt
```

As you can see, it looks like everything is working as expected.

Comment: I've replicated every single step listed above. Same result. Running the binary as `alice` prints (Real user: alice, Effective user: alice, This is foo.txt). Running the binary as `bob` prints (Real user: bob, Effective user: alice, /bin/cat: /home/alice/share/foo.txt: Permission denied). In other words, `bob` had the permission to run the binary, but somehow was unable to execute the `system()` instruction, as mentioned by Sato. Very very peculiar.

Comment: @JTJM I think I figured it out. See the update to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `foo.txt` file is in a share directory in `Alice home directory`,so Bob can not access the files in `Alice home directory` because of permissions.
you can create a `shared directory` in home, and givin both permissions to access this directory.

or, you can create a `shared directory` with `groupowner` of staff and set `SGID` bit with this command:

```
chmod 2777 sharedDir
```

when the `SGID` bit is set on a directory, new files or sub-directories created in the original directory will inherit the group ownership of the directory rather than be based on the user's current default group.

so when `Alice` create a file here, group ownership of the file will be **STAFF** and all of the member of this gorup can access these files base on `staff` group permission.

Comment: Correct in that `bob` can't read `foo.txt`. But `./display-foo` is setuid alice, which means it runs with alice's permissions and access rights, and the OP is asking why this program still can't read `foo.txt`.

Comment: @roaima my post has been updated